# how to properly implement a simple requestbuilder?

Tags: java, gwt, get

i made a small rpc app following this tutorial:  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gwt/gwt_rpc_communication.htm

it is working, but when i add a requestbuilder to the MessageServiceImpl.java in the server-directory like this

```
package ....
import  ....

public class MessageServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements MessageService{
public Message getMessage(String input) {
  Message message = new Message();      
  String url ="http://192.168.1.1/index.htm";

  RequestBuilder rb=new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET,URL.encode(url));
  try {
    rb.sendRequest("",new RequestCallback() {           
        @Override
        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
            message.setMessage(response.getText());
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
            message.setMessage(exception.toString());
        }
    });
  }
 catch (  RequestException e) {
  }
  return message;
 }
}
```

i am getting an errormessage ("Unable to obtain server response: 500 Server Error The call failed on the server; see server log for details") coming from the client-file that implements the entry-point.
It fails with any other url as well.

Can somebody kindly help me out? Thanks!